# Vim folding every line ending in { but not classes

Tags: regex, vim, regex-negation, folding

I intend to fold all the lines ending in `{` but not classes. So far I have came up with this command :

```
:%g/.\{-}\(class\)\@!.*{$/normal! zf%
```

But this would match also the lines containing `class`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems:

1. From `:help /\@!`: "You can't use "\@!" to look for a non-match before the matching position". Use `\@<!`, include the possible characters in between in there, and drop the useless (because it's not anchored) non-greedy first match.
2. The `:global` command places the cursor on the *first column* of matching lines, so add a `$` to make the `%` work all the time.
3. Subsequent inner folds must be defined with the outer fold open: `zv`.

Ergo:

```
:%g/\%(class.*\)\@<!{$/normal! $zvzf%
```