# Launch (:normal) command on vim start with .java files

Tags: vim, execute, autostart, autocmd

I want to put line in my `.vimrc` file so that it will fold the `/* ... */` like comments on autostart with `*.java` files.

So far I have came up with this but it does not want to work (although the command works in vim)

```
autocmd BufReadPre,BufReadPost,FileReadPre,FileReadPost *.java execute ":normal :%g/\/\*/normal! zf%"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The `:global` command already is an *Ex command*; there's no need for `:normal` (which is for stuff like `j`, `zf`, `/`). This should work:

```
:autocmd BufReadPre,BufReadPost,FileReadPre,FileReadPost *.java %g/\/\*/normal! zf%
```

- You probably don't need to run this both *before* and *after* reading a file.
- Vim can already detect the filetype; why duplicate the file pattern for Java files?! Better use the `FileType` event:

```
:autocmd FileType java %g/\/\*/normal! zf%
```

- Based on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20141984/813602), it looks like you want to set up elaborate *manual folding*. That's rather unusual, and I would recommend against it. Java has built-in folding based on syntax highlighting (though not for comment blocks, but you can grab that from `syntax/c.vim`); you enable it via

```
:setlocal foldmethod=syntax
```

If you really need custom folding, `:help fold-expr` is the way to go.

Comment: I was trying to get my head around `syntax/c.vim` but it's a little to much hassle for me.